# Machine learning analysis for data set

Tags: machine-learning, python, dataset, data-science-model, supervised-learning

I have a data set that contains houses, different features, and its prices. I'm trying to do an advanced analysis for this data set, I already did house price prediction analysis using different regression techniques like ridge regression, lasso regression, and elastic net regression.

Furthermore, I would like to do machine learning analysis with the data set. what kind of prediction can I do with the above data set? Someone has any ideas please tell me??

Answer (score 0):

you can develop simple predictive model like Linear regression to predict price of house given other features value, also analyse the features weight/coefficient and optimize your linear regression model.

Comment: @Anush I already develop a linear regression model also.. I need to do some thing except regression model, is possible to do clustering for this data set?

Comment: It depends on business requirement what you want at the end. but for exploration yes, you can work with classification models. Create Price Bins; Try Decision Tree, you can analyse how different variable effecting price. also you can try Support Vector Machines.